# extra spaces inserted with CKeditor's enterMode - causes problems in XML docs

Tags: php, xml, flash, ckeditor, whitespace

I am using CKEditor in my website's CMS, which spits out an XML file of CDATA enclosed content to be read by flash. The problem is that CKEditor, when its enterMode is set to `<p>` tags, creates a line break and a tab in the source which, when read by flash, enters space, even though I have ignoreWhiteSpace set to true. Any way to prevent ckeditor from using this behavior?

EDIT:

I still want to keep any <p> tags entered from within the editor - I just don't want all the extra space / tabs that get added in the actual source. If I use the above method, my actual code will be modified. What I'm getting if I view the source is this:

```
<p> 
    Donec at erat nec tortor sodales tempus.</p>
```

(an enter, and either a tab or a bunch of space after first <p> tag, instead of:

```
<p>Donec at erat nec tortor sodales tempus.</p>
```

(no spaces or breaks after <p> tag in source and I believe this is affecting the presentation of the XML. Does this help clarify at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually solved this on the Flash end, by using

```
TextField.condenseWhite = true;
```

and

```
XML.ignoreWhite = true;
```

Which doesn't change how CKEditor spits stuff out, but it does solve the problem of how flash displays it.

Answer (score 2):

You should test the "output for Flash" sample, here's a little snippet that changes just the part that you are asking, but the rest of the adjustments should be useful for you:

```
// Make output formatting match Flash expectations
var dtd = CKEDITOR.dtd;
for ( var e in CKEDITOR.tools.extend( {}, dtd.$nonBodyContent, dtd.$block, dtd.$listItem, dtd.$tableContent ) )
{
    dataProcessor.writer.setRules( e,
        {
            indent : false,
            breakBeforeOpen : false,
            breakAfterOpen : false,
            breakBeforeClose : false,
            breakAfterClose : false
        });
}
dataProcessor.writer.setRules( 'br',
    {
        indent : false,
        breakBeforeOpen : false,
        breakAfterOpen : false,
        breakBeforeClose : false,
        breakAfterClose : false
    });
```

Comment: wait - so this is javascript code that gets executed in the ckeditor init, or some sort of package that gets imported and run in flash?

Comment: It's javascript. All of the code is available in the "output for flash", you can find it in the samples folder.

Comment: How would one implement this if calling CKEditor via PHP?